# Visual studio 2010 automatically change project type

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-applications, tfs

Does anybody know why VS 10 change himself project type from Web Appliacation to Web Site when this project is downloaded from Team Foundation Server?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like someone has changed the application and checked it in that way...

Visual Studio won't change the project type on it's own.

Comment: But when I check out solution file and then compare version between my local file and last version on TFS I see differences

Comment: Is there any addon or tool in Visual Studio that could make that switch?

Comment: No I don't have any plugins in visual studio

Comment: Try use blame to see if someone has changed it. - Ok forgot this is TFS. Use SVN! :)

Answer (score 0):

Project type is stored in the project file, not in the solution file. Do a TFS compare (or view the history) on the project file to see if that was changed.

For C# project files the extension is .csproj

This site says "web applications" have a .csproj or .vbproj , but that a "website project" will not have a project file (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx). If the Web Application project was blasted away, and a web site created in its place, it may be difficult to track down when the change happened.